# threads accessing non-synchronised methods in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, thread-synchronization

can I ask to explain me how threads and synchronisation works in Java?

I want to write a high-performance application. Inside this application, I read a data from files into some nested classes, which are basically a nut-shell around HashMap.

After the data reading is finished, I start threads which need to go through the data and perform different checks on it. However, threads never change the data!

If I can guarantee (or at least try to guarantee;) that my threads never change the data, can I use them calling non-synchronised methods of objects containing data?

If multiple threads access the non-synchronised method, which does not change any class field, but has some internal variables, is it safe?

artificial example:

```
public class Data{
// this hash map is filled before I start threads
protected Map<Integer, Spike> allSpikes = new HashMap<Integer, Spike>();

public HashMap returnBigSpikes(){
     Map<Integer, Spike> bigSpikes = new HashMap<Integer, Spike>();

     for (Integer i: allSpikes.keySet()){
         if (allSpikes.get(i).spikeSize > 100){
         bigSpikes.put(i,allSpikes.get(i));
         }
     }

     return bigSpikes;
}
}
```

Is it safe to call a NON-synchronised method returnBigSpikes() from threads?

I understand now that such use-cases are potentially very dangerous, because it's hard to control, that data (e.g., returned bigSpikes) will not be modified. But I have already implemented and tested it like this and want to know if I can use results of my application now, and change the architecture later...

What happens if I make the methods synchronised? Will be the application slowed down to 1 CPU performance? If so, how can I design it correctly and keep the performance?

(I read about 20-40 Gb of data (log messages) into the main memory and then run threads, which need to go through the all data to find some correlation in it; each thread becomes only a part of messages to analyse; but for the analysis, the thread should compare each message from its part with many other messages from data; that's why I first decided to allow threads to read data without synchronisation).

Thank You very much in advance.

Comment: is `returnBigSpikes` accessed by multiple threads at a time?

Comment: yes. it's not a real example, but my the application already works like this.

Comment: I think your code would work safe without using synchronization..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `allSpikes` is populated before all the threads start, you could make sure it isn't changed later by saving it as an [unmodifiable map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap%28java.util.Map%29).

Assuming `Spike` is immutable, your method would then be perfectly safe to use concurrently.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that Spike must be immutable/ thread safe. That is the potential issue here.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you have a bunch of threads where you can guarantee that only one thread will modify a resource and the rest will only read that resource, then access to that resource doesn't need to be synchronised. In your example, each time the method returnBigSpikes() is invoked it creates a new local copy of bigSpikes hashmap, so although you're creating a hashmap it is unique to each thread, so no sync'ing problems there.

Comment: "In general, if you have a bunch of threads where you can guarantee that only one thread will modify a resource and the rest will only read that resource, then access to that resource doesn't need to be synchronised" - Not quite incorrect. This situation can cause a race condition. If you mean the write occurs first (before any other thread), then ALL reads occur AFTER any write, then ok.

Answer (score 1):

As long as anything practically immutable (eg. using final keyword) and you use an unmodifiableMap  everything is fine.

I would suggest the following UnmodifiableData:

```
public class UnmodifiableData {
     final Map<Integer,Spike>  bigSpikes;
     public UnmodifiableData(Map<Integer,Spike> bigSpikes) {
         this.bigSpikes = Collections.unmodifiableMap(new HashMap<>(bigSpikes));
     }
     ....
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your plan should work fine. You do not need to `synchronize` reads, only writes.

If, however, in the future you wish to cache `bigSpikes` so that all threads get the same map then you need to be more careful about synchronisation.

Comment: it was not a real example... However, even if all threads get the same map, but still does not modify it, it is still safe, right?

Comment: Yes it is safe. The complexity arises if you cache the sub-maps somehow (like `bigSpikes` in your sample). You have to make the caches `volatile` and consider what happens of two threads start building the cached map at the same time. If you build all of the sub-maps before starting the threads then this, again, is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html), it will do all syncronization work for you. Its bettr, then making synronization around ordinary HashMap.

Comment: yes, but I could have other structures as well. And my question is more general, I want also to know if I can use such a design in the future. Will not ConcurrentHashMap slow down my application during reads/gets?

Comment: In practice it will work without failure if you read and do not modify data. In theory you are breaking a Java Memmory Model rule, what is a bad practice. If you dont like CuncurrentHashMap, have a look at ReentrantReadWriteLock.

Answer (score 0):

Since allSpikes is initialized before you start threads it's safe. Concurrency problems appear only when a thread writes to a resource and others read from it.

Comment: and what about variables inside the non-synchronised method? E.g., 'Map<Integer, Spike> bigSpikes' and 'Integer i'. Will each thread call its own "instance" of the method?